# Get location of client machine using ip address

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the location of client machine using ip address. Client can access the internet only if
he/she provide the proxy authenication.
Let us say client need to access the 'www.google.com' on the browser then immediately Authenication Required
prompt window open and then client enter his/her username and password. But it is possible the few users does 
not required the provide the authenication in order to access internet.

This segment of code does not helped me...

```
string url = "http://freegeoip.net/xml/";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

WebProxy proxyObj = new WebProxy("http://freegeoip.net/xml/");
proxyObj.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Uri uri = new Uri(url);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(uri));
XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(url);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
ms.Position = 0;
doc.Load(ms);
ms.Dispose();
```

In the above code if i add network credential instance with username, password and domain then it's work perfectly
Instead of providing the default net credential in code itself, I need to get the username and password from the users(client
machine).

My question is how to prompt the Authentication Required Window and get the username and password to load the download from url
I would be glad if someone throw light on this issue...

Edit: Somehow basic authentication window prompt and now i can get the username and password which can use for credential

```
try
        {
             var reg = HttpContext.Current.Request;


             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reg.Headers["Authorization"]))
             {
                 var cred = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Request.Headers["Authorization"].Substring(6))).Split(':');
                 var user = new { Name = cred[0], Pass = cred[1] };
                 string url = "http://freegeoip.net/xml/";
                 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                 WebProxy wProxy = new WebProxy();
                 ICredentials crd;

                 crd = new NetworkCredential("'" + cred[0] + "'", "'" + cred[1] + "'");

                 wProxy = new WebProxy("myproxy", true, null, crd);

                 wc.Proxy = wProxy;

                 Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                 string content = wc.DownloadString(uri);

             }
             else
             {
                 try
                 {

                     //var reg = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reg.Headers["Authorization"]))
                     {
                         var res = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                         res.StatusCode = 401;
                         res.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm = \"freegeoip\"");
                         //res.End();
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {

                 }
             }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

But Still It throwing the "Unable to connect to the remote server"